# Media screen query not working in iPhone

Tags: css, media-queries

I need a css media query for iPhone4 (width:340;height:480) & iPhone
    5 (width:340;height:570). Both in portrait mode.

```
For iPhone 5 
@media only screen and (max-width : 340px) and (max-height : 570px)
 {
  body
 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 340px;
  height: 570px;
  z-index: 45;
  }
 .row2 
{
 position: absolute;
 left: 0px;
 top: 0px;
 width: 340px;
 height: 570px;
 z-index: 44;
}
._2_1
     {
 position: absolute;
 left: 4px;
 top: 151px;
 width: 80px;
 height: 78px;
 z-index: 43;
 }
 }

For iPhone 4

              @media only screen and (max-width : 340px) and (max-height : 480px)
                  { 
                  /*styles*/
                  }
```

This code not working in iPhone 5. While loading in iPhone 5, it loads with iPhone 4's css

Sample css

```
@media only screen and max-width : 570px) {
        body 
         {
            position:absolute !important;
            left: 0px;
            top: 0px;
            width: 340px;
            height: 570px;
            z-index: 45;
        }
        .row2 {
            position:absolute !important;
            left: 0px;
            top: 0px;
            width: 340px;
            height: 570px;
            z-index: 44;
        }
        ._2_1 {
            /*background-image: url("images/2 1.png");*/
            position:absolute !important;
            left: 4px;
            top: 151px;
            width: 80px;
            height: 78px;
            z-index: 43;
        }
        ._2_2 {
            position:absolute !important;
            left: 118px;
            top: 150px;
            width: 82px;
            height: 80px;
            z-index: 42;
        }
    }.........
.......
}
```

Comment: if possible add your css classes that you are using inside them and also generic css sample

Comment: @RaunakKathuria It has several classes...

Comment: some sample or snippet of your css will also do.. add what are you adding in media queries

Comment: Try this link http://www.stephen.io/mediaqueries/

Comment: @RaunakKathuria i've edited the quetion with some snippets.Please find them.

Comment: @Anon Thanks.But i've seen this already.Not working :(

Comment: Yikes, you got many issue there. First the iPhone width is 320px not 340px and then you have !important rules which get even more complicated. See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

From [this site:](http://stephen.io/mediaqueries/#iPhone)

iPhone 2G-4S in portrait

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) 
and (orientation : portrait) 
{ 
   /* STYLES GO HERE */ 
}
```

iPhone 5 in portrait:

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 568px) 
and (orientation : portrait) 
{ 
  /* STYLES GO HERE */ 
}
```

Comment: @user2376463 - try switching the order of the media queries. First iphone4 then iphone5

Comment: Maybe the classes you are using in iphone4 are more specific. Try adding !important to (some of) your iphone5 rules - does it work now?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

For Iphone4

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 480px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (device-aspect-ratio: 2/3)
{
    ...
}
```

For iphone5 only (landscape and portrait mode)

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 568px) 
and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (device-aspect-ratio: 40/71)
{
   ...
}
```

Any particular mode say portrait

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 568px)
and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (device-aspect-ratio: 40/71) and (orientation:portrait)
{
   ...
}
```

**[Reference](https://coderwall.com/p/mwvbea)**

Comment: Nothing can be changed means? are you using any tool to test or on iphone itself?

Comment: Till loads iphone 4's css for iphone 5.

Comment: Can you give this a try for iphone5
@media (device-height: 568px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {}

Comment: Yes.But still loads iphone 4's css for iphone 5

Comment: Final try :) iPhone < 5: media screen and (device-aspect-ratio: 2/3) {}
iPhone 5: media screen and (device-aspect-ratio: 40/71) {}

Answer (score 0):

Try this with `min-height` and `max-height`

For iphone 4

```
  @media only screen and (max-width : 340px) and (max-height : 480px)
   { 
    /*styles*/
   }
```

For iphone 5

```
@media only screen and (min-height: 480px) and (max-height : 570px)
  {
   /* styles*/
  }
```

Comment: @Danield No. No. check the `min-height` instead of `max-width` in the second section.

Comment: Are you checking in real devices?

Answer (score 0):

You can check this website for CSS related issues [CSS TRICKS](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)

Answer (score 0):

/* iPhone 2G-4S in portrait & landscape */ @
    media only screen
    and(min - device - width: 320 px)
    and(max - device - width: 480 px)
    and(-webkit - device - pixel - ratio: 2) and(device - aspect - ratio: 2 / 3) { /* STYLES GO HERE */ }

```
/* iPhone 5 & 5S in portrait & landscape */
@
media only screen
and(min - device - width: 320 px)
and(max - device - width: 568 px)
and(-webkit - device - pixel - ratio: 2) and(device - aspect - ratio: 40 / 71) { /* STYLES GO HERE */ }

/* iPhone 6 in portrait & landscape */
@
media only screen
and(min - device - width: 375 px)
and(max - device - width: 667 px)
and(-webkit - device - pixel - ratio: 2) and(device - aspect - ratio: 667 / 375) { /* STYLES GO HERE */ }


/* iPhone 6 plus in portrait & landscape */
@
media only screen
and(min - device - width: 414 px)
and(max - device - width: 736 px)
and(-webkit - device - pixel - ratio: 3) and(device - aspect - ratio: 16 / 9) { /* STYLES GO HERE */ }
```

If you need to only specific orientation media query then just add to and (orientation:portrait), and (orientation:landscape).